# decomposing multiplication of two matrices to the sum of rank-1 matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

Suppose we have two matrices:

> $D_{n \times k}$ and $X_{k \times p}$

I need to understand how do we decompose the multiplication DX to the sum of $k$ (am I correct about $k$?) rank_$1$ matrices.

Comment: You want to decompose the *product* $DX$ as a sum of rank 1-matrices?

Comment: @Calle: Yes, that's what I want.

Comment: Compute the product $DX$, then compute its singular value decomposition.

Comment: Could you elaborate, please? @calle. I need to know how those two are rekated, sum of k rank 1 matrices and svd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need for the SVD.  The point of this question is just to understand the "columns times rows" way of viewing matrix multiplication.

Let $D = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & \cdots & a_k \end{bmatrix}$
and $X = \begin{bmatrix} b_1^T \\ b_2^T \\ \vdots \\ b_k^T \end{bmatrix}$.
Then
\begin{equation}
D X = a_1 b_1^T + \cdots + a_k b_k^T
\end{equation}
and each term in the sum is a rank $1$ matrix.